# querySelectorAll not working with Cloned item

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a copy of the original container div with the `cloneNode` method in javascript inside the container there are 3 buttons with `btn` class, when I make a copy of the original one the last only the last element in the copied item is only printing hello in the console, any ideas?

```js
let add = document.querySelector('.add-button');
const item = document.querySelector('.container');

let btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  makecopy();
});

btn.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("hello")

  })
});

function makecopy() {

  let copiedItem = item.cloneNode(true);
  item.parentNode.insertBefore(copiedItem, item);
}
```

```html
<div class="add-panel">
  <button type="button" class="add-button">Create new</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">+</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">+</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">+</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: It all worked for me? Your issue is though when you create new ones.

Comment: when you create new the first 3 are printing hello? , yeah exactly only when i create new and make a copy of the original div

Comment: Okay so what you need to do is make another event listener on each make-copy? This will give each button their listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only setting up event listeners on the first set of buttons, not the cloned ones. Instead of setting up listeners on each button, use ["event delegation"](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to allow the event to "bubble" up to a common ancestor and handle the event there. This way, all the newly added elements will immediately work without needing their own handler and there is only one handler that needs to be set up instead of many.

You've also got some redundant code and code that will no longer be needed when you take this approach.

```js
// No need to set up an anonymous handler that calls the real one. Just
// register the real one
document.querySelector('.add-button').addEventListener('click', makecopy);
const item = document.querySelector('.container');

function makecopy() {
  let copiedItem = item.cloneNode(true);
  item.parentNode.insertBefore(copiedItem, item);
}

// Listen for clicks on the document:
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // Check to see if it was a button that was clicked:
  if(event.target.classList.contains("btn")){
    console.log("hello");
  };
});
```

```html
<div class="add-panel">
  <button type="button" class="add-button">Create new</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">+</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">+</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just appears you weren't adding new listeners when you made new buttons. Some adjustments.

```js
let add = document.querySelector('.add-button');
const item = document.querySelector('.container');

let btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  makecopy();
});

btn.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("hello")

  })
});

function makecopy() {

  let copiedItem = item.cloneNode(true);
  item.parentNode.insertBefore(copiedItem, item);
copiedItem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("hello")

  })
}
```

```html
<div class="add-panel">
  <button type="button" class="add-button">Create new</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">+</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">+</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">+</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: copiedItem in this case may reference more than what you want, but it's a start, I'd maybe create new element per click and register it then for ease, a loop after wards is easy to deploy.

Comment: thank you, I  just thought that querySelectorAll works for all the classes even the copied one.

Comment: Anytime you add more elements that call for querySelectorAll needs to be called again to tally them all up. However if you do that and loop them you may set duplicate listeners that will hinder your app. So find an appropriate method to handle this and for me it'd to create and set listener with a removal point upon init of each box. :)